# How to set javadoc for com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES jars?

Tags: android, eclipse

While browsing through a sample Android project, I tried to get the javadoc for an Android class (android.view.Menu) that was being referenced in the code, and I noticed it didn't have a reference to the javadoc.  I looked in the project properties, and I saw that it was referencing two libraries, "Android 2.2" and "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES".  The former was just a reference to "android.jar" for a particular API level, and the javadoc was set for that jar.  However, "android.view.Menu" was not in that jar.  This "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES" thing doesn't provide a setting for a javadoc path.

I thought perhaps this is something I can set up in the SDK manager, but I didn't see any way to do that.

Can someone provide more background on what's going on here, and whether there's a reasonable way to get the javadoc associated with that library?

Comment: I have the same problem. Also When I run one of my apps on emulator, I get this warning and it never runs. > "emulator[223:10b] Warning once: This application, or a library it
> uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should
> cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz." At the begining, my other apps worked just fine on emulator. But after two or three launching there are any application on the emulator. Now I couldn't see any app icon to try. I think these problems are associated. So what can i do?